# Unhandled GraphQL subscription error ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to setup a subscription with my React Native app and Rails Graphql server but I get the following error mess

> Unhandled GraphQL subscription error ReferenceError: document is not defined

I'm suspecting one of the library that I use is using document but not sure which one and the exemple I followed was a setup for a React app instead of React Native.

I followed this guide: https://haughtcodeworks.com/blog/software-development/graphql-rails-react-standalone/

Here is my app.js setup

...

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: `${global.URL}/graphql`,
})

const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable')

const hasSubscriptionOperation = ({ query: { definitions } }) => {
  return definitions.some(
    ({ kind, operation }) => kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription',
  )
}

const link = ApolloLink.split(
  hasSubscriptionOperation,
  new ActionCableLink({cable}),
  httpLink
)
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

return (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Root />
  </ApolloProvider>
)
```

I'm open to sharing more of my code but since I'm not sure where the error could come from I would need some guidance first.

Comment: A screenshot of the error stack trace will help more in finding a root cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben mentioned the tutorial is for React and not React Native, however, it does use Apollo, and for that reason I managed to make it work by instead of using the **_subscribeToNewLinks** method, I used the Apollo useSubscription hook and it worked! However, I'm still having issue with the channel transmission not working every time.

```
const { data: subscriptionData, _error, _loading } = 
  useSubscription(NEW_LINKS, {
  shouldResubscribe: true,
  onSubscriptionData: () => refetch()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The guide you showed is not for react native, but just for react **AND** react-dom. I think you know this already which is why you removed the `document.getElementById('root')`, but you didn't know that `graphql-ruby-client`, for some reason needs the DOM. It relies on document, and in react native, there is no `document` object in the global scope. This is only available in browsers.

I would suggest using a different graphQL client, for example [Apollo Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-client)